# How to find particular node in XML and all of its child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formatlist>
<format>
    <formatName>WHC format</formatName>
    <delCol>ID</delCol>
    <delCol>CDRID</delCol>
    <delCol>TGIN</delCol>
    <delCol>IPIn</delCol>
    <delCol>TGOUT</delCol>
    <delCol>IPOut</delCol>
    <srcNum>SRCNum</srcNum>
    <distNum>DSTNum</distNum>
    <connectTime>ConnectTime</connectTime>
    <duration>Duration</duration>
</format>
<format>
    <formatName existCombineCol="1">Umobile format</formatName>   //this format
    <delCol>billing_operator</delCol>
    <hideCol>event_start_date</hideCol>
    <hideCol>event_start_time</hideCol>
    <afCombineName dateType="DateTime" format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">  //node i want
        <name>ConnectdateTimeAFcombine</name>
        <combineDate>event_start_date</combineDate>
        <combineTime>event_start_time</combineTime>
    </afCombineName>
    <afCombineName dateType="DateTime" format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">  //node i want
        <name>aaa</name>
        <combineDate>bbb</combineDate>
        <combineTime>ccc</combineTime>
    </afCombineName>
    <modifyPerfixCol action="add" perfix="60">bnum</modifyPerfixCol>
    <srcNum>anum</srcNum>
    <distNum>bnum</distNum>
    <connectTime>ConnectdateTimeAFcombine</connectTime>
    <duration>event_duration</duration>
</format>
</formatlist>
```

I want to find format with Umobile format then iterate over those two nodes.

```
<afCombineName dateType="DateTime" format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">  //node i want
    <name>ConnectdateTimeAFcombine</name>
    <combineDate>event_start_date</combineDate>
    <combineTime>event_start_time</combineTime>
</afCombineName>
<afCombineName dateType="DateTime" format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">  //node i want
    <name>aaa</name>
    <combineDate>bbb</combineDate>
    <combineTime>ccc</combineTime>
</afCombineName>
```

and list all the two node's child nodes. The result should like this:

```
ConnectdateTimeAFcombine,event_start_date,event_start_time.
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var children in format.Descendants())

  {

     //Do something with the child nodes of format.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For all XML related traversing, you should get used to using XPath expressions. It is very useful. Even if you could perhaps do something easier in your specific case, it is good practice to use XPath. This way, if your scheme changes at some point, you just update your XPath expression and your code will be up and running.

For a complete example, you can have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Xml namespace APIs along with System.Xml.XPath namespace API. Here is a quick algorithm that will help you do your task:

1. Fetch the text node containing the string **Umobile format** using the below XPATH:

   XmlNode umobileFormatNameNode = document.SelectSingleNode("//formatName[text()='Umobile format']");
2. Now the parent of umobileFormatNameNode will be the  node that you are interested in:

   XmlNode formatNode = umobileFormatNameNode.ParentNode;
3. Now get the  children for this  node:

   XmlNodeList afCombineFormatNodes = formatNode.SelectNodes("afCombineName");
4. You can now process the list of afCombineFormatNodes

   for(XmlNode xmlNode in afCombineNameFormtNodes)
   {
        //process nodes
   }

Comment: thank you,u are right. can i use Xpath like this:  XmlNodeList umobileFormatNameNode = document.SelectNodes("//formatName[text()='Umobile format']/afCombineName");

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... yes you can directly fetch the node list in the manner you proposed too.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can access those elements:

```
var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("PATH TO YOUR XML FILE");
var result = doc.Descendants("format")
            .Where(x => (string)x.Element("formatName") == "Umobile format")
            .Select(x => x.Element("afCombineName"));
```

Then you can iterate the `result` this way:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    string format = item.Attribute("format").Value.ToString();
    string name = item.Element("name").Value.ToString();
    string combineDate = item.Element("combineDate").Value.ToString();
    string combineTime = item.Element("combineTime").Value.ToString();
}
```